# iPhone : Hiding the tab bar on the current view

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a way to hide and show the tab bar on the current view you are on.  So not with **setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed** because this only works to the view that is pushed.

You can do it with the navigation controller

```
[view.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

But surely there is a way to do it with a Tab bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code to your applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(toggleTabBarHidden) 
                                            name:@"toggleTabBarHidden" 
                                          object:nil];
```

Make a method in your appDelegate like so:

```
-(void)toggleTabBarHidden{
        for(UIView *view in self.window.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            if(view.hidden){
                view.hidden = NO;
                break;
            }
                view.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to show/hide your UITabBar, just fire the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"toggleTabBarHidden" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

This will work from anywhere within your app.

Comment: Awesome idea however a tabbar item does not support hidden by the looks of it.

Comment: Did work, did not animate but I think that's asking too much.  Thank you

Comment: That's not asking too much, you can do that with animation blocks. They're super easy to implement. I *love* them. Here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html You'll just want to animate the alpha property from 1.0 to 0.0 over about 0.5 seconds.

Comment: You can also make it slide off the screen by animating the origin point of the frame property. I spent *hours* messing around with UIView animations when I discovered them.

Comment: @Aurum Aquila 

Genius idea..and if you have an outlet connected to your tab controller, you can simplify it even further by replacing your for loop with: tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

Comment: @Warebot, I had that originally. The problem was that it was going to hide the view that the user was in as well, and he didn't want to use `tabBar.enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could to this is by embedding your Tab Bar Controller within a Navigation Controller, then when you push onto the navigation controller the tab bar controller will slide out, tab bar and all.

Comment: The tabbar controller is the root controller and it has then child navigation controllers.

Comment: You can still do this, you end up with a complex view hierarchy though (you'd have to insert a NavigationController at your root). If you look at Apple's apps generally when they want to hide the Tab Bar they present a view on top of the tab bar controller modally.

Comment: Really, that's interesting to know.  Its weird it does not support the hidden property.  I need to animate this down